# If $f$ is a non-constant entire function, can $f(z + T_n) = f(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ is a non-constant entire function, can $f(z + T_i) = f(z)$ for all $i \geq 1$ if $T_i \to 0$ as $i \to \infty$ and $\{ T_i \}_{i \geq 1} \neq 0$ for each $i \geq 1$?

My idea is to write both $f(z + T_i)$ and $f(z)$ in a power series and solve the recursion $z^n = (z + T_i)^n$. The RHS can be expanded further by the Binomial theorem. I eventually reduced it to the point where all the $(n-1)$th are grouped together. But I haven't gotten any good ideas on how to proceed from there forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z) = f(z) - f(0)$.  Then $g$ is entire, and $g(T_i) = f(T_i) - f(0) = g(0) = 0$ for all $i$. Thus the zeros of $g$ are not isolated.

Comment: Sorry, and the last line implies that $g$ is constant?

Comment: Reason I asked is because I thought the zeroes of nonconstant entire functions *are* isolated. So I m not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: That is right. Under your stated hypothesis, $g$ would have a non-isolated zero at $z = 0$, implying that $g$ is constant.